# В частности

Tags: пунктуация

"В частности(,) правильная постановка знаков препинания." Нужна ли здесь запятая? И почему?

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с [@виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799), но если с *"в частности"* начинается предложение, то эту вводную конструкцию стоит отделить запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует написать все предложение полностью, но предположим, что оно звучит так: "Для грамотности важно все, в частности правильная постановка знаков препинания". Здесь запятая не нужна, так как вводное слово "в частности" стоит в начале присоединительного оборота.

Comment: Согласен с Валентином. Предположим, предложение звучит так: "Для грамотности важно все. В частности, правильная постановка знаков препинания делает письменную речь грамотной"